To ensure that there is no $E$-field inside the superconductor and Faraday's law holds true the surface current seems to eliminate its cause, why?
In a Faraday's induced EMF experiment with a superconducting loop, the current at the surface of the superconducting loop creates a magnetic field that nullifies the magnetic field created by the Bar-magnet. So there is no changing magnetic field in the area enclosed by the loop now. As there is no changing magnetic flux in the closed surface there can't be any induced electric field along the loop (even at the surface) to drive the current. Then what makes the current go on and adjust itself so that it can nullify the varying magnetic field created by the bar magnet all the time? What is the machinery behind this self-adjusting current at the surface? We can't say Faraday's law creates an electric field just outside the surface which is responsible for the current flow anymore, as according to Faraday's law there is no induced Electric field at the surface now but the current still going on and changing itself according to the varying motion of the bar magnet. To ensure that the Electric field is zero everywhere inside the superconductor and at the same time Faraday's law to obey the current at the surface seems to eliminate the crucial thing that is needed for its very existence.

It's a superconductor, so you don't need an emf for a current to flow. The current that was set up originally persists.

The question here seems to be precisely about the transient effects when this current is "set up" as you say.

Indeed, even without resistance, creating a current flow would at least have to overcome the inductance, so it would seem as if an $E$-filed would be needed for that. But the reasoning in this question may not be correct. If the magnetic field is turned on (or equivalently, the magnet is moved closer) there may be a transient region in time where there is a little bit of flux partly penetrating the superconductor, which means there are regions close to the surface where a transient $E$-field is present for a short time. After all we don't claim that the field cannot penetrate a superconductor for all frequencies, especially not if $f\rightarrow\infty$.
See drawing below, situation A may be transient, while B is the final state.
The green circle shows where a transient $E$ field is present. In other regions (like the red circle) there may be none, or much less. Exactly those regions where the final state needs a high surface current (where there will be a strong $B$-field adjacent to the surface) are also the regions where the initial transient would be strongest.
NB: I do not claim that the mechanism necessarily is accurately described here, the point is just that something like this could happen and resolve the paradox.

